# E2E protractor test suit : downloaded file from test app to jenkins workspace fails though on local system works

Tags: jenkins, protractor, ui-automation, fs, google-chrome-headless

**Issue :** File getting downloaded in one of e2e tescases is not getting saved to given folder in jenkins workspace

**Setup :** jenkins + protractor + cucumber + headless browser (chrome).

**seetings :**

```
capabilities: 
{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
     args: ['--headless','window-size=1366,768'],
        prefs: {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
             'default_directory': process.cwd()+'/Commons/downloads/'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

**Code :**

```
var workbook = XLSX.readFile(process.cwd()+'/Commons/downloads/test.xls');
```

**whats happening :** 
 Same setup is working fine on my system : File gets downloaded to respective project folder and i am able to read it .

**jenkins** throws

```
"error_message": "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/jenkins_build/workspace/Projects/Project123/e2e-Test/Commons/downloads/test.xls'\n    at Error (native)\n    at Object.fs.openSync .
```

**Tried :**

1. Replacing process.cwd() with process.env.WORKSPACE.
2. creating a file using above paths .

   var fd = fs.openSync(process.env.WORKSPACE+'/Commons/downloads/test1.txt', 'w');

*It successfully creates a file at desired workscope folder . This shows that path is correct and accesscible i think.*

*Can it be a issue that jenkins not allowing that downloaded file due
to access /security related policies ? .*

Comment: have you tried by adding relative path instead of process.cwd()?

Comment: I have tried with using "'/opt/jenkins_build/workspace/Projects/Project123/e2e-Test/Commons/downloads/test.xls" and process.env.WORKSPACE + "/Commons/downloads".  Downloaded file doesn't get saved at location given in chrme option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor file download test fails when headless chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831273/protractor-file-download-test-fails-when-headless-chrome)

Comment: Where is the code that actually downloads. Potentially it is an async method and you have not downloaded it yet?