# angular ng e2e testcase with file download not working with headless chrome

Tags: angular, download, protractor, google-chrome-headless, angular-e2e

In an angular2+ project I have an e2e testcase that clicks a button, a file gets downloaded, and the content is checked. It works in normal mode, but not in --headless mode. The file is not downloaded, and the testcase times out.

In my protractor.conf.js I already tried a lot of flags I found in different places:

```
const os = require('os');
[...]

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-popup-blocking', '--no-sandbox', '--window-size=1024,768', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', "--disable-dev-shm-usage"],
      prefs: {
        'download': {
          'prompt_for_download': false,
          'directory_upgrade': true,
          'default_directory': os.homedir() + '/Downloads'
        }, 
        safebrowsing: {enabled: false, disable_download_protection: true},
        browser: {set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' }}
      }
    }
  },
```

Without success.

Also I read somewhere that you could configure it like this

```
// works for headless and "normal" mode
browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
    'behavior': 'allow',
    'downloadPath': DOWNLOAD_DIR
});
```

But there is no "sendChromiumCommand" in any "browser" variable, neither in the protractor.conf.js nor in the spec ts file.

How can I get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor file download test fails when headless chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831273/protractor-file-download-test-fails-when-headless-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution to this.

Add these lines to your `protractor.conf.js`:

```
exports.config = {
  ...
  onPrepare() {
    ...
    browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
      behavior: 'allow',
      downloadPath: downloadsPath
    });
  }
};
```

From: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c196

Comment: Thanks. Sadly it doesn't work - the test case just times out.

Comment: You can have look at it working here: https://github.com/DanielHabenicht/ngx-vcard/blob/master/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts

Comment: How can I execute these? git clone, npm install, ng e2e yields this:
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-vcard'.
src/app/app.component.ts(3,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-vcard'.
src/app/app.module.ts(7,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-vcard'.

Comment: you have to build the library before (as I am using the project for an npm package run `npm run build:lib` before)

Comment: Hehe I just did "npm install ngx-vcard" in there lol.
Anyways I got sth to work comparing our code to your example, so thx a lot!